# How to convert an NSString to an unsigned int in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, unsigned

My application gets handed an `NSString` containing an `unsigned int`.  NSString doesn't have an `[myString unsignedIntegerValue];` method.  I'd like to be able to take the value out of the string without mangling it, and then place it inside an `NSNumber`.  I'm trying to do it like so:

```
NSString     *myUnsignedIntString = [self someMethodReturningAString];
NSInteger    myInteger            = [myUnsignedIntString integerValue];
NSNumber     *myNSNumber          = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:myInteger];

// ...put |myNumber| in an NSDictionary, time passes, pull it out later on...

unsigned int myUnsignedInt        = [myNSNumber unsignedIntValue];
```

Will the above potentially "cut off" the end of a large `unsigned int` since I had to convert it to `NSInteger` first?  Or does it look OK to use?  If it'll cut off the end of it, how about the following (a bit of a kludge I think)?

```
NSString     *myUnsignedIntString = [self someMethodReturningAString];
long long    myLongLong           = [myUnsignedIntString longLongValue];
NSNumber     *myNSNumber          = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:myLongLong];

// ...put |myNumber| in an NSDictionary, time passes, pull it out later on...

unsigned int myUnsignedInt        = [myNSNumber unsignedIntValue];
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!  :)

Comment: To request support for reading unsigned values from NSString, please visit http://bugreport.apple.com and file a dupe of radar://2264733 against component `Foundation | X`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first version truncates and the second should be fine as long as your number actually fits into an unsigned int - see e.g. [*"Data Type Size and Alignment"*](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/transition/transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001064-CH207-SW1).
You should however create the `NSNumber` using `+numberWithUnsignedInt`.

If you know that the encoding is suitable, you could also simply go with the C-libraries:

```
unsigned n;
sscanf([str UTF8String], "%u", &n);
```